# jssor image-gallery.source.html $Cols:

Tags: jssor

Modified the original value for $Cols: in jssor image-gallery.source.html from 10 to 8 after increasing the thumbnail size.  Thumbnails have been realigned but the current image icon is no longer positioned in the center of the thumbnail navigator, it is now offset one to the right.  What changes are necessary to move the current image icon one thumbnail to the left?

Answer (score 0):

Please change $Align option value, which indicates where the current slide should park.

Comment: Working now.  Thumbnails are aligned and current image indicator is in the center.  Thank you.